# Java enum and if statement, is there a better way to do this?

Tags: java, enums

I have an java `Enum` class, and at runtime I will read in a value from command line, and I want to correspond this value to a value in my `Enum` class. `Shipper` is my Enum Class. Is there a better way do this this, instead of `if` and `else if` below? This look ugly.

```
private List<Shipper> shipperName = new ArrayList<Shipper>();
...
public void init(String s){ 
    if(s.equals("a")){
        shipperName.add(Shipper.A);
    }else if(s.equals("b")){
        shipperName.add(Shipper.B);
    }else if(s.equals("c")){
        shipperName.add(Shipper.C);
    }else if(s.equals("d")){
        shipperName.add(Shipper.D);
    }else if(s.equals("e")){
        shipperName.add(Shipper.E);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

Here is my Shipper.class

```
public enum Shipper
{
    A("a"),
    B("b"),
    C("c"),
    D("e"),
    F("f")
;

    private String directoryName;

    private Shipper(String directoryName)
    {
         this.directoryName = directoryName;
    }

    public String getDirectoryName()
    {
         return directoryName;
    }
}
```

Comment: (And if `s` doesn't match any name?)

Comment: @Tom: Then error will be printed.

Comment: That's not what the code says (and I'm a great believe in believing code over documentation).

Comment: @Tom: just update the code. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes add the string into the enum's constructor (specify a constructor in the enum which takes a String) and create the enums with a text value of a, b , c. Etc. Then implement a static factory method on the enum which takes a string and returns the enum instance. I call this method textValueOf. The existing valueOf method in enum cannot be used for this. Something like this:

```
public enum EnumWithValueOf {

    VALUE_1("A"), VALUE_2("B"), VALUE_3("C");

    private  String textValue;

    EnumWithValueOf(String textValue) {
        this.textValue = textValue;
    }

    public static EnumWithValueOf textValueOf(String textValue){

        for(EnumWithValueOf value : values()) {
            if(value.textValue.equals(textValue)) {
                return value;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No EnumWithValueOf
                            for value: " + textValue);  
    }   
}
```

This is case insensitive and the text value can be different to the enum name - perfect if your database codes are esoteric or non descriptive, but you want better names in the Java code.  Client code then do:

```
EnumWithValueOf enumRepresentation = EnumWithValueOf.textValueOf("a");
```

Comment: "The existing valueOf method in enum cannot be used for this."  Why?

Comment: Because you'll get "The enum EnumClassName already defines the method valueOf(String) implicitly"

Comment: It wasn't clear from the original question that the value could be different from the enumeration name.

Comment: Not sure why the above solution has been ticked. I can see 2 errors. Firstly the VALUE_2 and VALUE_3 are both "B", although this may be a typo. But more importantly, the textValueOf() method is not null safe.

Answer (score 6):

```
shipperName.add(Shipper.valueOf(s.toUpperCase()));
```

If the name doesn't always match the enumeration you can do something like this

```
public static Shipper getShipper(String directoryName) {
    for(Shipper shipper : Shipper.values()) {
        if(shipper.getDirectoryName().equals(directoryName)) {
            return shipper;
        }
    }
    return null; //Or thrown exception
}
```

Comment: Note valueOf() will throw a IllegalArgumentException if it doesn't find a matching enumeration.

Comment: I dont want to use `toUpperCase` here, since it is not always the case of `a` -> `A`. The real case is some thing like this `uspsx` -> `USPS_EXPRESS`. Is there a way, I just update my code, can u take a look?

Comment: I added additional code that does what you want (I think).  You can put the code in the enumeration itself.

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me try :D

Answer (score 3):

You can get an Enum from the valueOf() method:

```
public void init(String s) {
    try {
        Shipper shipper = Shipper.valueOf(s.toUpperCase());

        shipperName.add(shipper);
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

If it is not just a simple a -> A case, then it might be an idea to create a HashMap with key=>value pairs:

```
private HashMap<String, Shipper> map;

public void init(String s) {
    if(map == null) {
        map = new HashMap<String, Shipper>();
        map.put("a", Shipper.A);
        ... //b => B code etc
    }

    if(map.containsKey(s)) {
        shipperName.add(map.get(s));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I dont want to use `toUpperCase` here, since it is not always the case of `a` -> `A`. The real case is some thing like this `uspsx` -> `USPS_EXPRESS`. Is there a way, I just update my code, can u take a look?

Comment: I've made changes to it :) I hope it helps!